# Devise current_user found in a controller but missing in another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Devise and Omniauth. So, I'm supposed to have a `current_user` method available in my controllers. Indeed, for example, in my `tasks_controller`:

```
  def index
    @tasks_remaining = Task.where(:user => current_user, :done => false)
    @tasks_done = Task.where(:user => current_user, :done => true)
  end
```

`current_user` does work as expected. Very oddly, RubyMine warns me that `current_user` is not found and underlines it gray. But this piece of code works anyway.

However, in my `authentications_controller`,

```
def create
    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
    if authentication
      sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
    else
      current_user.authentications.create(:provider => ominauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
      flash[:notice] = "success"
      redirect_to authentication_url
    end
  end
```

Here, I get an error when that line with `current_user` executes. It says:

```
undefined method `authentications' for nil:NilClass
```

I have debugged to this point and found that `current_user` variable is indeed not present in this scope.

So, why is it working in one controller and missing in another? I'm using Rails 4 and Ruby 2. I'm following Railscast 235 and 236.

Comment: make sure you are using `authenticate_user!` in `before_filter` on your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error does not mean that current_user method, is not found it returns nil because nobody is signed in.

```
def create
  omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
  if authentication
    flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
    sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
  elsif current_user
    current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
    flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
    redirect_to authentications_url
  else
    user = User.new
    user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
    if user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
      sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
    else
      session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

have you written condition like 'elsif current_user' in your authentications controller code?

as i see you have copied this code from railscasts omniauth #1, i suggest watching railscasts omniauth #2 also.

Comment: Hi @sachin-sing yes, I've watched the second part too and updated my code accordingly. But still getting that error. :(